# Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu, compilation-errors

i tried compiling a program to upload sensor readings that i connected with my ESP8266 to cloud (in my case, Antares) but i keep getting this error message. Can anyone tell me where the problem is, and what do i need to do to get it fixed ?

At first i thought it was because come incompatibility with my older version of Arduino IDE, so i updated to the latest version of it, but nothing changed.

Im kinda new here, so any suggest might help. Thank you!

Arduino: 1.8.13 (Windows Store 1.8.42.0) (Windows 10), Board: "NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module), 80 MHz, 115200, 4M (3M SPIFFS)"

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp: In member function 'void AntaresESP8266HTTP::get(String, String)':

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:202:23: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'setCACert_P'

```
 bool res = client.setCACert_P(caCert, caCertLen);

                   ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:222:16: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'verifyCertChain'

```
 if (client.verifyCertChain(_serverNoHttp)) {

            ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp: In member function 'String AntaresESP8266HTTP::getRaw(String, String)':

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:274:23: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'setCACert_P'

```
 bool res = client.setCACert_P(caCert, caCertLen);

                   ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:294:16: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'verifyCertChain'

```
 if (client.verifyCertChain(_serverNoHttp)) {

            ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp: In member function 'void AntaresESP8266HTTP::send(String, String)':

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:439:23: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'setCACert_P'

```
 bool res = client.setCACert_P(caCert, caCertLen);

                   ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:459:16: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'verifyCertChain'

```
 if (client.verifyCertChain(_serverNoHttp)) {

            ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp: In member function 'void AntaresESP8266HTTP::sendRaw(String, String, String)':

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:512:23: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'setCACert_P'

```
 bool res = client.setCACert_P(caCert, caCertLen);

                   ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:532:16: error: 'class WiFiClientSecure' has no member named 'verifyCertChain'

```
 if (client.verifyCertChain(_serverNoHttp)) {

            ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp: In member function 'void AntaresESP8266HTTP::getLatestTest(String, String)':

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:688:40: error: no matching function for call to 'WiFiClient::connect(String&, uint16_t&)'

```
 if(client.connect(_server, _portNum)) {

                                    ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:688:40: note: candidates are:

In file included from C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/ESP8266WiFi.h:39:0,

```
             from C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.h:5,

             from C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\libraries\antares-esp8266-http-master\src\AntaresESP8266HTTP.cpp:1:
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClient.h:47:15: note: virtual int WiFiClient::connect(IPAddress, uint16_t)

virtual int connect(IPAddress ip, uint16_t port);

```
           ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClient.h:47:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'String' to 'IPAddress'

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClient.h:48:15: note: virtual int WiFiClient::connect(const char*, uint16_t)

virtual int connect(const char *host, uint16_t port);

```
           ^
```

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\ArduinoData\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.3.0\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src/WiFiClient.h:48:15: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'String' to 'const char*'

exit status 1

Error compiling for board NodeMCU 1.0 (ESP-12E Module).

This report would have more information with
"Show verbose output during compilation"
option enabled in File -> Preferences.

Comment: please format the printout ... put these three symbols  ``` on a blank line before the printout ... same after the printout ... make sure that there is nothing else on the line

Comment: check the esp8266 core version in Boards Manager

Comment: As noted by @Jurajj, You’re working with an old ESP8266 Core version (2.3.0 is from 2016). Update it and try again (and it would be nice if you could report back here).

Comment: It turned out that the ESP8266 core version that i had installed is obsolete, so i installed the esp8266 core version 2.7.4 and the compiling works just fine. Thank you so much everyone for the help ! :D